# JavaMail Decoding Issue when reading email

Tags: java, utf-8, jakarta-mail

```
      Part part1 = multi.getBodyPart(i);
      if (part1.isMimeType("text/plain") && !Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part1.getDisposition())) {
        txtBody = part1.getContent().toString();
        System.out.println("txtBody: " + txtBody);
      }
```

I received a German email, but the print text body is messy code. Is there any place I can set the coded format?
eg. "*****Löschen oder ändern Sie die Authentifizierungsinformationen unter dieser Zeile nicht!*****"

Comment: Sorry, I need a lot more details before I can help you.  If the message is formatted correctly, JavaMail will decode it correctly.  What exactly do you mean by "messy code"?  Note that displaying non-ASCII characters on the console (System.out) doesn't always work right on all machines; it depends on what character encoding your operating system is configured for among other things.  The characters can be correct, but just not be displayed correctly.

Comment: I use JavaMail to read a message from a .eml file. The content can be displayed correctly using Outlook to open it. But some characters on the console (System.out) displayed like a '?'.  I find that the '?' in the eml file are German HTML Code. Do JavaMail has the ability to handle this? Or any other solutions?

Comment: It's usually not JavaMail, it's the console.  Write a trivial program that prints a constant string with the same German characters, does it display correctly?